# Bootstrap table in div horizontal scroll not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the content, I put a div with a table inside. I need it to scroll horizontally. I've spent hours researching and trying some solutions.

```
<div style="width:100%; overflow: scroll;">
    <table style="width:2000px;">
            <tr>
                <td>very large width table with scroll horizontal</td>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>x</td>
                <td>x</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

[image: safari test]

[image: chrome test]

[image: div 1500 px]

Comment: You just want to be able to scroll horizontally when the table is wide, ride? Because your code already does that for me. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: It seems to work for me -- https://jsfiddle.net/0k9a2h10/ -- what problem are you having? If on OS X, know that the default behavior is to not show scrollbars. So you won't see them unless you toggle that setting or add fake scrollbars. With a touchpad, the JSFiddle I linked to scrolls horizontally.

Comment: does not work here, what could be wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using bootstrap,instead of using styles use the inbuilt classes.

```
<div class="table table-responsive">
   <table >  //give width styling as you want.
        <tr>
            <td>very large width table with scroll horizontal</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

This will give you a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: i test in chrome, does not work, what could be wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @MarcoCosta but could you show your code? Bcz this should show a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: I believe this won't work because `table-responsive` only displays the scroll bar on small devices with a screen width of less than 768px. See documentation for details: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive

Answer (score 3):

at first.you should add class name 'table-responsive' to the div element which is the container element of the table.

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed small">
  /* table content here */
  </table>
</div>
```

second. if you want the effect that all content in the table display only on one line without soft wrap.you should add css style to your style sheet with content as below:

```
th,td{
    /*use this property to disbale soft wrap*/
    white-space: nowrap;
    /*To make extra certain,add this css property*/
    word-break: keep-all;

}
```